# Oracle Apex - Comma Separated LOV

Tags: sql, list, select, oracle-apex

I'm using Oracle Apex 4,2. I have a table with a column in it called 'versions'. In the 'versions' column for each row there is a list of values that are separated by commas e.g. '1,2,3,4'.
I'm trying to create a Select List whose list of values will be each of the values that are separated by commas for one of the rows. What would the SQL query for this be?

**Example:**

Table Name: Products

```
Name     | Versions
--------------------
myProd1  | 1,2,3
myProd2  | a,b,c
```

Desired output:
Two Select Lists.
The first one is obvious, I just select the name column from the products table. This way the user can select whatever product they want.
The second one is the one I'm not sure about. Let's say the user has select 'myProd1' from the first Select List. Then the second select should contain the following list of values for the user to select from: '1.0', '1.1' or '1.2'.

Comment: Please put some sample data and/or desired output. Both is better. It is too hard to understand what you are looking for.

Comment: @Art added sample data and desired output, thanks for the advice, any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, still do not understand what are you looking for. Put the output in table format, e.g. columns, values... Use ctrl+K to format the code.

Comment: Where these .0, .1, .2 are coming from? Do you have a table or you simply need to concatenate your existing value 1 with .0, then with .1, .2, .4... if myProd1 is selected? It seems pretty simple to do. Same question for all other products. Is this what you are looking for: SELECT 'myProd1' myProd1, '1.0,1.1,1.2' From dual; ??? I'll try to figure this out tomorrow... Make it clear.

Comment: I've changed the example a bit to hopefully make it easier to understand what I want.
The formatted code in the example is my Table that is called Products.
I want 2 select lists.
The First select list simply lets the user choose either myProd1 or myProd2.
The second select list then lets the user choose which of the versions they want for the product name that they chose.
So if the user chose myProd1, then the second select list will contain the following list of values: '1','2' or '3'.
Whereas if the user chose myProd2, second select list will have following list of values: 'a','b' or 'c'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reading your latest comments I understand that what you want is not an LOV but rather list item. Although it can be an LOV too. The first list item/lov will have all products only that user selects from it, e.g. Prod1, Prod2, Prod3... The second list item will have all versions converted from comma separated values as in your example to table as in my examples below. Because in my understanding user may pick only a single value per product from this list. Single product may have many values, e.g. Prod1 has values 1,2,3, 4. But user needs to select only one. Correct? This is why you need to convert comma values to table. The first query select is smth lk this:

```
SELECT prod_id
  FROM your_prod_table
 /

 id      
 --------
 myProd1 
 myProd2 
 .....
```

The second query should select all versions where product_id is in your_prod_table:

```
 SELECT version FROM your_versions_table
   WHERE prod_id IN (SELECT prod_id FROM your_prod_table)
 /

 Versions
 --------
 1,2,3,4   -- myProd1 values
 a,b,c,d   -- myProd2 values
 .....
```

The above will return all versions for the product, e.g. all values for myProd1 etc...

Use my examples converting comma sep. values to table. Replace harcoded '1,2,3,4' with your value column from your table. Replace dual with your table name

If you need products and versions in a single query and single result then simply join/outer join (left, right join) both tables.

```
SELECT p.prod_id, v.version 
  FROM your_prod_table     p
     , your_versions_table v
  WHERE p.prod_id = v.prod_id
 /
```

In this case you will get smth lk this in output:

```
 id      |  Values
 ------------------
 myProd1 | 1,2,3,4
 myProd2 | a,b,c,d
```

If you convert comma to table in above query then you will get this - all in one list or LOV:

```
 id      |  Values
 ------------------
 myProd1 | 1
 myProd1 | 2
 myProd1 | 3
 myProd1 | 4
 myProd2 | a
 myProd2 | b
 myProd2 | c
 myProd2 | d
```

I hope this helps. Again, you may use LOV or list values if available in APEX. Two separate list of values - one for products other for versions - make more sense to me. In case of list items you will need two separate queries as above and it will be easier to do comma to table conversion for values/versions only. But is is up to you.

Comma to table examples:

```
-- Comma to table - regexp_count --
SELECT trim(regexp_substr('1,2,3,4', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) str_2_tab
  FROM dual
 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= regexp_count('1,2,3,4', ',')+1
/

-- Comma to table - Length -
SELECT trim(regexp_substr('1,2,3,4', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) token
  FROM dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= length('1,2,3,4') - length(REPLACE('1,2,3,4', ',', ''))+1
/

-- Comma to table - instr --
SELECT trim(regexp_substr('1,2,3,4', '[^,]+', 1, LEVEL)) str_2_tab
  FROM dual
 CONNECT BY LEVEL <= instr('1,2,3,4', ',', 1, LEVEL - 1)
/
```

The output of all that above is the same:

```
STR_2_TAB
----------
1
2
3
4
```

Comma to table - PL/SQL-APEX example. For LOV you need SQL not PL/SQL.

```
DECLARE
  v_array apex_application_global.vc_arr2;
  v_string varchar2(2000);
BEGIN
-- Convert delimited string to array
   v_array:= apex_util.string_to_table('alpha,beta,gamma,delta', ',');

  FOR i in 1..v_array.count LOOP
    dbms_output.put_line('Array: '||v_array(i));
  END LOOP;

 -- Convert array to delimited string
  v_string:= apex_util.table_to_string(v_array,'|');
  dbms_output.put_line('String: '||v_string);
END;
/
```